# Configure the run command

Tags: rust, geany

I begin to use geany to play with rust under Windows 10.
I would like to configure the "run command" to read stdin from a file (e.g. my_program < in.txt)

[image]

I am only interest with "run command". I tried to write "< in.txt", "<" "in.txt" in the first or in the second box of the line "run", nothing works.
Have you a solution ?
Thank you for any tips.

Comment: I found the solution : I wrote **cmd /K "%e < in.txt"** in the first box of the "Run" line

Comment: Please write an actual answer, or delete your question. Comments are not for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : I wrote cmd /K "%e < in.txt" in the first box of the "Run" line.

[image]